# dataframe rolling apply return a array

Tags: dataframe

```
df['a'].rolling(window=500).apply(lambda x: [1,1])
```

seems `apply` for `rolling` is only allowed to return a value. How do I return a array?

Since `apply` for dataframe is allowed to return a array, we can build like:

```
shifted_df = pd.concat([df['a'].shift(i) for  i in range(499,-1, -1)], axis=1)
```

to replace `rolling`. But since my `df` has a large number of rows, `shifted_df` exceeds the limit of memory. Therefore this way not works.